# show one div and hide the rest using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this script that shows/hides a div. Could anyone please explain how I can get it to show only one div at a time?

```
<script>
function Show_Div(Div_id) {
if (false == $(Div_id).is(':visible')) {
    $(Div_id).show();
}
else {
    $(Div_id).hide();
}
}
</script>
```

and the link...

```
onClick="Show_Div(Div_1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655741/javascript-hide-all-other-divs

Comment: if you're already using jQuery, why not `$("div").hide(); $("#myDiv").show()`?

Comment: Thanks 'The Guest' used the info in your link and solved my problem :)Thanks to everyone else for you help too!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.parent  div').hide(); // hide div's on load using parent class as a starting point     
     $('#nav a').click(function() {  // on the anchor clicks that are inside div with id=nav
        var $div = $('.parent div').eq($(this).index('#nav a'));  // get the relevant div
        $div.show();  // show the relevant div
        $('.parent div').not($div).hide();  // hide all but the relevant div
    });​
}):
```

Comment: Thanks Navy, I used the link above in the end but appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

if i understand your question correctly , maybe you can try this way:

```
<script>
function Show_Div(Div_id) {
    if (false == $(Div_id).is(':visible')) {
        $(this).show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

if your use `this` in

```
$(this).show();
```

the only one will toggle which your click~
but in this way :

```
$(Div_id).show();
```

you will get a array of target , because the selector of Jquery will select a array of target .

hope it will help you~

Comment: Thanks Qianjiahao, I used the link above in the end but appreciate your help too!